# Syntax errors, but no errors and code runs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every once in a while my Visual Studio Code starts highlighting in Jupyter Notebooks syntax errors on correct code, that, indeed, runs just fine.

Example:

[image: correct code (executed) with errors]

If I change the indentation and put everything where it was, I got the same code with different errors:

[image]

Restarting the kernel does not have any effects: as soon as the cell is run, the errors appear again. Restarting VSC solves the problem, but it is a pain in the neck to restart it every time this happens.

This is too strange to be a bug, may be it is related to some plugins I am using. Before starting to look for the responsible, is there anyone here who had and solved a similar problem?

My VSC:

```
Version: 1.63.2 (user setup)
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:40:02.816Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

Comment: I had similar issues when parsing some code picked from the web. The indent was not properly detected in the editor and would raise some warnings without error.
I notice your warnings are also related to indent, it should be easy to detect if that's indeed the problem.

Comment: In my case I typed the code so it cannot be related to some weird copy&past issues.